# Do I need to delete a pointer if I haven't assigned it a new value?

Tags: c++, pointers, delete-operator

Just a quick question:

Do I need to delete a pointer if I haven't actually assigned a new value to it?

What I've done if created a pointer and then handed it a reference to something like so:

```
Planet *planetPointer;

planetPointer = &earth;
```

Do I need to delete this pointer or can I just set it to null?

Comment: Only `delete` what you `new`.

Comment: To be a little more pedantic than @chris: The rule is that for *every* new you should have a delete at *some* point, and for every new[] you should have a delete[] at some point.

Comment: Duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12513426/what-happens-when-delete-pointer-to-stack-object?lq=1

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ calling delete on variable allocated on the stack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441831/c-calling-delete-on-variable-allocated-on-the-stack)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You don't need to delete it, and, moreover, **you shouldn't delete it**. If `earth` is an automatic object, it will be freed automatically. So by manually deleting a pointer to it, you go into undefined behavior.

Only `delete` what you allocate with `new`.

Comment: To put it another way: If you didn't `new` the object, you don't have ownership of it (unless relevant documentation says otherwise), and if you don't have ownership of it you shouldn't deallocate it.

Comment: Even worse, in a way, is when `earth` is a reference to a dynamically allocated object. Assuming that other author was a good citizen, that earth object will eventually be freed by the thing that allocated it. Delete it here and the program will fail on that later deletion. The reason this is nastier is because the error message makes it appears that the error is at the second delete. The author of the `earth`-allocating code will inevitable receive a nasty phone call or email saying "Your code is broken! It's dropping core."