# Is this a system resource? (or how do I know if I need to delete a pointer) - working with C in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, time, delete-operator

Looking at this [cplusplus.com time example](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/time/), got me thinking more about pointers. The code has no `delete` (and no `new`).

Warning: I generally try to avoid pointers as much as possible, so I am definitely not proficient.

I've cut a lot of the code from the example below so as to focus on my question:

```
/* time example */
#include <stdio.h>      /* printf */
#include <time.h>       /* time_t, struct tm, difftime, time, mktime */

int main ()
{
  time_t timer;
  time(&timer);  /* get current time; same as: timer = time(NULL)  */

  return 0;
}
```

Should I delete timer at the end of this, or is this just pointing to a system resource? My understanding is that whenever I use `new`, I should use `delete`. Is it right to think that as I am not using `new`, I don't need `delete`.

[This stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13709284/do-i-need-to-delete-a-pointer-if-i-havent-assigned-it-a-new-value) seems to be what I am looking for and explains I don't need `delete` (which matches the example code on the website) as I am not doing a `new`; however, I am not sure the functions I am using are not calling a `new` somewhere (as I find it very hard to read the source). How do I know? Do I need to know?

I really hate working with this old time code and can't wait for the upcoming C++20 `chrono` update, but this is too far away for my project.

Comment: Don't delete stack variables IF the object itself is on the stack as the function `epilogue` will free up the working of the function `prolog`. When you called `time` you passed the `address of timer (a.k.a. &timer)`. The `time` function merely took the `address of timer`. Let's just imagine and assume that `time_t` on your architecture was `typedef`'d as an `int`, think of it as just passing a pointer of an `int` to the `time` function, where inside the `time` function, it does something like `*timer_addr = 777`. What else confuses you?

Comment: In your code, you would not do `free(&timer)` in C since that will give undefined behaviour, since `timer` is not created using `malloc()`.  Similarly, `delete &timer` will also give undefined behaviour in C++, since `timer` is not created with a `new` expression.

Comment: So timer is not created, but refers to a system timer that already exists?

Comment: @David: `timer` is created in `main` and is destroyed when `main` returns.

Comment: @MSalters If this was created deeper in the program, it wouldn't get freed until the entire thing finishes. Is that correct? Can I free it earlier?

Comment: @David: Objects which are local to a function are destroyed exactly when the function returns. `new` and `delete` are a way around that, but this is less often needed than you would think.

Comment: @MSalters sorry to keep asking, but this object is not local to the function. It's a pointer meaning it needs to be explicitly deleted to free up memory, does it not? I am assuming this is a system object that exists if you request a reference to it or not, meaning there is not need to delete it.

Comment: @David:You can't tell from a mere pointer whether it needs to be `delete`'d, `free`'d, or whether it just points to an object whose lifetime is managed directly by C++. You have to look back, and match the disposal with the creation. `new/delete`, `malloc/free`, neither/neither.

Answer (score 5):

Short answer:

**No!**

---

Long answer:

You don't have a pointer in your code that is pointing to memory allocated with `new`, so you are not required to `delete` anything. And, your reasoning is correct that whenever you allocate something in your code, you are responsible to de-allocate that as well. It is best to use [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization) (**Resource Acquisition Is Initialization**) to manage resources that need to be de-allocated.

For your question regarding the internal allocations by an API, as a programmer **you** yourself are responsible to go through the API's documentation to figure that out. Some APIs require you to de-allocate the allocated memory in a particular way, which is (ideally) very well documented, and you should follow that.

In C, memory allocated with [`malloc()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/malloc) must be de-allocated with [`free()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/free).

In C++, memory allocated with [`new`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) or `new[]` must be de-allocated with [`delete`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/delete) or `delete[]`, respectively.

BTW, you ought to use C++11's smart pointers ([`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) and [`std::shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) along with [`std::make_unique`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) and [`std::make_shared`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared) respectively) to enforce RAII in your code whenever possible.

Comment: You commented on using smart pointers, but in this case we can't do that as we aren't creating the object. Is that correct? We could use a smart pointer if we were 'newing' the object.

Comment: @David: You are correct! In your case, you don't have any `new`. Use smart pointers instead of raw pointers; and, use `std::make_unique` and `std::make_shared` instead of `new`.

Answer (score 0):

You just can `delete` `timer` if define it as a pointer like this with `new` keyword :

```
time_t *timer = new time_t(50);
// do something with *timer
delete timer;
```

In bellow case :

```
{
    time_t timer;
    time(&timer);
}
```

You just pass `timer` address with `&` (reference sign) and `time_t timer` and it stored in **stack**. At the end of block it will be delete automatically.

Comment: I just updated the question title and detail (after you posted your response).

Comment: Does the function time use 'new' anywhere? Am I responsible for deleting this?

Comment: @David there's no need (if you want define it as `time_t timer`). actually its arbitrary to define it as a pointer or as a normal variable.

Comment: @David notice, just `delete` what you `new`.

Comment: Calling `&` the "reference sign" is very misleading. C++  uses it for at least three purposes : as the address-of operator, as a bitwise `and`, and when defining reference types. (And that's ignoring `&&`).