# How to delete objects from vector of pointers to object?

Tags: c++, memory, vector

I am trying to understand how to delete a vector of pointers, and the pointed objects, in memory. I have started with a simple example, found in another thread, but I get "pointer being freed was not allocated" error.

What I am doing wrong?

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    std::vector <int *> vec;

    int a = 2;
    int * b = &a;

    int c = 3;
    int * d  = &c;

    vec.push_back(b);
    vec.push_back(d);

    for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++) {
        delete vec[i];
    }
    vec.clear();

}
```

Comment: You only delete if you `new`'d.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only call delete on variables that were created with new
Check this link:
[Calling delete on variable allocated on the stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441831/c-calling-delete-on-variable-allocated-on-the-stack)

Comment: OK - So if instead of a vector of int *, I had some Objects * (instantiated by new), then it would have worked?

Comment: @Bibi541 If you had a vector of `int*` full of elements instantiated by `new`, it would have worked.  `int*` just means "address of an `int`" -- not "reference to an `int` I own".

Comment: @Bibi541, Then you'd realize that cleaning them up yourself was a royal pain, especially in terms of exception-safety, and you'd use a smart pointer and live happily forever after.

Answer (score 2):

You're deallocating memory that was allocated on the stack with automatic storage. That's why you're getting errors.

Only `delete` things you allocated with `new`. [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) will take care of the rest.

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
int a = 2;
```

You are allocating a int on stack and anything on stack does not need to `delete`, it will be freed automatically once we left the scope it is declared. Therefore in your code, you are trying to free the same thing twice.

Whilst if you do

```
int* a = new int(2);
```

You will then allocate a int on heap, where data will not be deleted unless you explicitly call `delete`.

The bottom line is, `new` and `delete` should always be written in pairs.