# Pointer to STL Container Thread Safety (Queue/Deque)

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, stl

I currently have a bit of a multi-threading conundrum. I have two threads, one that reads serial data, and another that attempts to extracts packets from the data.  The two threads share a queue.  The thread that attempts to create packets has a function entitled parse with the following declaration:

```
Parse(std::queue<uint8_t>* data, pthread_mutex_t* lock);
```

Essentially it takes a pointer to the STL queue and uses pop() as it goes through the queue looking for a packet.  The lock is used since any pop() is locked and this lock is shared between the Parse function and the thread that is pushing data onto the queue.  This way, the queue can be parsed while data is being actively added to it.

The code *seems* to work for the most part, but I'm seeing invalid packets at a somewhat higher rate than I'd expect.  My main question is I'm wondering if the pointer is changing while I'm reading data out of the queue.  For example, if the first thread pushes a bunch of data, is there a chance that where the queue is found in memory can change?  Or am I guaranteed that the pointer to the queue will remain constant, even as data is added?  My concern is that the memory for the queue can be reallocated during my Parse() function, and therefore in the middle of my function, the pointer is invalidated.

For example, I understand that certain STL iterators are invalidated for certain operations.  However, I am passing a pointer to the container itself.  That is, something like this:

```
// somewhere in my code I create a queue
std::queue<uint8_t> queue;
// elsewhere...
Parse(&queue, &lock_shared_between_the_two_threads);
```

Does the pointer to the container itself ever get invalidated?  And what does it point to?  The first element, or ...?

Note that I'm not pointing to any given element, but to the container itself.  Also, I never specified which underlying container should be used to implement the queue, so underneath it all, it's just a deque.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

EDIT 8/1:

I was able to run a few tests on my code.  A couple of points:

1. The pointer for the container itself does not change over the lifecycle of my program.  This makes sense since the queue itself is a member variable of a class.  That is, while the queue's elements are dynamically allocated, it does not appear to be the case for the queue itself.
2. The bad packets I was experiencing appear to be a function of the serial data I'm receiving.  I dumped all the data to a hex file and was able to find packets that were invalid, and my alogrithm was correctly marking them as such.

As a result, I'm thinking that passing a reference or pointer to an STL container into a function is thread safe, but I'd like to hear some more commentary ensuring that this is the case, or if this is implementation specific (as alot of STL is...).

Comment: Maybe I missed it, but are you *not* using the `lock` on both `push()` and `pop()` operations? If not, you should be.

Comment: Sorry, yes, the lock is used for ALL push and pop operations.  As far as I can tell, there should be no concurrency issues from these operations.

Comment: Could you design a single-threaded test of your parsing algorithms, to eliminate the potential thread-safety issues as a potential cause? Basically, capture a large amount of raw data, construct a queue, and then let your parser loose on it, and see if you have the same problems.

Comment: Yes!  Now that I think about it, in my reader thread, I can just push the data to a hex dump file.  From there, I can just use the Parse function on the file, therefore breaking any dependency on threading.

Comment: Ran some tests today in a multithreaded environment, see the above edit.

Comment: Anything not thread-safe becomes safe to do when you've properly implemented locking. It sounds like you have, so I think your suspicion a thread-safety was just ill-founded.

Comment: Yea, I'm a C guy originally, so I'm sometimes suspect about things like containers doing things that I don't know about that are causing bugs.  Thanks for suggesting that I run a few more tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are worried that modifying a container (adding/deleting nodes) in one thread will somehow invalidate the pointer to the container in another thread. The container is an abstraction and will remain valid unless you delete the container object itself. The memory for the data maintained by the containers are typically allocated on the heap by [`stl::allocators`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/allocator/).

This is quite different from the memory allocated for the container object itself which can be on the stack, heap etc., based on how the container object itself was created. This separation of the `container` from the `allocator` is what's preventing some modification to the data from modifying the container object itself.

To make debugging your problem simpler, like Jonathan Reinhart suggests, make it a single threaded system, that reads the stream AND parses it.

On a side note, have you considered using [Boost Lookfree Queues](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/lockfree.html) or something similar. They are designed exactly for this type of scenarios. If you were receiving packets/reading them frequently, locking the queue for reading/writing for each packet can become a significant performance overhead.

Comment: "unless you delete the container object itself" unless the object is *destroyed* (as you correctly mentioned they can be "on the stack" as well, where they don't get *deleted*)

Comment: Yup. 'Deleting' an stack object is definitely [not recommended](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441831/c-calling-delete-on-variable-allocated-on-the-stack) :).