# Debug Assertion Failed on Linked List Destructor (C++ Visual Studio)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I've been working on trying to create a singly linked list in C++ on Visual Studio but keep running into this weird bug. When I test the list everything works perfectly fine in testing except when it comes to deleting the list. For some reason whenever I call delete on it, I get a popup from Visual Studio with the following messages in this order:

Debug Assertion Failed!
Expression: _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)

Debug Assertion Failed!
Expression: _CtrilsValidHeapPointer(pUserData)

Debug Assertion Failed!
Expression: _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)

The way I designed the list, head is a pointer to a dummy node that does not hold any data members. Here is the code wwhich was found to be causing problems:

```
int main() {
SSLL<char> list;
list.push_back('A');
delete &list;
}
```

Comment: Show how you're adding nodes

Comment: I just added it. Thanks for looking over it!

Comment: The comment seems fine, can you also add the construction and destruction of the list?

Comment: I just did. I appreciate you taking the time to look over this.

Comment: Wow I just caught it. I never actually created an object to delete since I didn't intiialize with new... Thank you for helping to direct me in that direction! Wow after staring at my class code for so long I can't believe it was something in the main.cpp file. Thanks so much! You're awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
int main() {
  SSLL<char> list;
  list.push_back('A');
  delete &list; // WRONG!
}
```

your class is a **stack local object**, you don't need to call `delete` on its address: it will automatically be destroyed when it gets out-of-scope.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to delete [variable allocated on stack](http://gribblelab.org/CBootcamp/7_Memory_Stack_vs_Heap.html), you should call `delete` only on the memory allocated by `new`, this was already covered in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/441837/1149736).

Perhaps you wanted to use [`std::vector::clear()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/clear/) just to erase list (although it's not necessary, memory gets freed by vectors destructor).