# "Debug Assertion" arrays, header files and declarations

Tags: c++, arrays, header

I have made a header file which contains an array of a fixed size (17) but there is something fundamentally incorrect and I cannot find what.

**ScreenArray.h**

```
    class ScreenArray
    {
    public:
        ScreenArray();
        ~ScreenArray();
        unsigned long getColour(int arrayPointer);
        void setColour(int arrayPointer, unsigned long pixelColour);
    private:
        unsigned long pixelArray[17];
    };
```

**ScreenArray.cpp**

```
#include "PixelScreenArray.h"

ScreenArray::ScreenArray()
{

}

ScreenArray::~ScreenArray()
{
    delete[] pixelArray;
}

unsigned long ScreenArray::getColour(int arrayPointer)
{
    return pixelArray[arrayPointer];
}

void ScreenArray::setColour(int arrayPointer, unsigned long pixelColour)
{
    pixelArray[arrayPointer] = pixelColour;
}
```

**Source.cpp**

```
...
ScreenArray sA;
sA.setPixel(0, 3242);
...
```

Comment: You don't need to `delete` the array as you didn't allocate it with `new`

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't allocate the array with `new[]` you shouldn't `delete[]` it, this is wrong:

```
class ScreenArray
{
public:
    ScreenArray();
    ~ScreenArray() {
       delete[] pixelArray; // Nope
    }
private:
    unsigned long pixelArray[17];
};
```

the array is a member of the class and whether the entire object is allocated on the stack as you did:

```
ScreenArray sA;
sA.setPixel(0, 3242);
```

or allocated on the heap with a `new ScreenArray();`, you can't "*just delete part of the object away*".

In your specific case you're trying to free stack memory and [that's UB](https://stackoverflow.com/q/441831/1938163)