# delete a series of object created using new in another function from the main function

Tags: c++, pointers, new-operator, delete-operator

I came across a piece of code that use `new` to allocate dynamic memory in a function, then calls this function in the main function. I suspect there are some memory leak issue, but I do not know exactly how to fix it. The following code is simplified to demonstrate the problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

 // Definition for singly-linked list.
 struct ListNode {
     int val;
     ListNode *next;
     ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(NULL) {}
 };

ListNode* createList(void);

int main(){
    ListNode* my_list = createList();
    //... some code 
    
    //  how to delete those objects created by new?
    return 0;
}

ListNode* createList(void) {

    ListNode preHead(0), *p = &preHead;
    vector<int> sum = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

    for (decltype(sum.size()) i = 0; i != sum.size(); i++){
        p->next = new ListNode(sum[i]);
        p = p->next;
    }

    return preHead.next;
}
```

If I understand it correctly, The function `createList()` creates a list which has 6 ListNode objects.
Except the first object in the list (which is `preHead`), the other 5 objects are all dynamically
allocated using `new`. Finally, function `createList()` returns a pointer to the second object in the list,
which is a pointer to dynamic memory.

#### My question is:

1. Is `my_list` a normal pointer or pointer to dynamic memory? How do we decide the type of `my_list`.for example, if I write the following code

   `ListNode l1(2);ListNode* my_list = &l1;`

Then `my_list` will be a normal pointer to ListNode object. What is the difference between the 2 situations?

2. The last 5 objects in the list are created using `new`, how to delete them in `main()` after using the list? Do I have to traverse the list and start deleting from the end of the list until all objects created dynamically are deleted?
3. If that is the case, I think it will be cumbersome and inconvenient. How to improve `createList()` under the condition that it still returns a pointer to ListNode object.

Comment: I have to ask: why not just use `std::list`? The stdlib has many ways to spare you from ever having to wrangle with lifetime issues.

Comment: As you already seem to be using std::vector, the correct solution is to use std::list  or std::forward_list, or indeed std::vector.

Comment: the code is from leetcode, I have to use the predefined struct to solve the problem, so the use of list or forward_list is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Agreeing with the aforementioned suggestions of using std::list, I want to add the following: 
Q1) where do you see the distinction between a "normal pointer" and "pointer to dynamic memory"? A pointer to x is a pointer to x. You should know whether it is yours to delete. 
Q2) You either do what you suggested (deleting from the end) or

```
void clearList(ListNode* p) { 
  ListNode* nextP; 
  while (p != NULL) {
    nextP = p.next;
    delete p;
    p = nextP;
  }
}
```

Comment: I thought the two are different as you can't use `delete` to delete “normal” pointer, sorry, I do not know how to call them.  If pointer to dynamic memory and pointer to normal object are the same, how should the compiler know if you can use `delete` operation on a pointer.

Comment: The compiler does not know about that. This is your responsibility.

Answer (score 1):

> Is my_list a normal pointer or pointer to dynamic memory?

your pointer is a pointer, it is a variable that points to memory, there really is no difference between a pointer that points to memory that was dynamically allocated or memory that isn't.  The only difference is you have to clean up dynamically allocated memory that you own.(Which you should know if you allocated it dynamically or not)

A safe alternative to dynamic memory is to use `std::shared_ptr` and `std::unique_ptr` I won't go into a lot of detail here but they can save you some trouble with memory management, so look them up.

> How do we decide the type of my_list.for example, if I write the
>   following code
>
> ListNode l1(2); ListNode* my_list = &l1;

This is a pointer to memory allocated on the stack (So not dynamic as you didnt call new)

> The last 5 objects in the list are created using new, how to delete
>   them in main() after using the list? Do I have to traverse the list
>   and start deleting from the end of the list until all objects created
>   dynamically are deleted?

Yes, you could loop through them all and delete them that way if you would like, but how are you going to get to the previous?  Another solution is to do:

```
ListNode* tempPtr;
while(my_list)  // This works since you are initializing next to null.
{
    tempPtr = my_list->next;
    delete my_list;
    my_list = tempPtr;
}
```

> If that is the case, I think it will be cumbersome and inconvenient.
>   How to improve createList() under the condition that it still returns
>   a pointer to ListNode object.

There really isn't, if you don't dynamically allocate your memory here or use a static or global variable, it will be gone at the end of the function.  You could however use a `std::vector` or an `std::list` to do the exact same thing you are currently doing.

Comment: How does the compiler know if you can use `delete` with a pointer if there are no difference between pointer to dynamic memory and pointer which does not?

Comment: As Gerriet said to you on his answer, the compiler doesn't know, see:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441831/calling-delete-on-variable-allocated-on-the-stack

Comment: If the compiler does not know, how can the dynamically allocated memory be deleted. This is strange.

Comment: @jdhao Nothing strange about it. The compiler's job is to pass a pointer to the library implementation of `free()`, not check it. If the library receives a pointer to memory allocated in the right way, that memory is deallocated. If you pass a pointer to something that wasn't dynamically allocated, or dynamically allocated by a different source, you've written ill-formed code, and the behaviour of your program is undefined - so anything can happen, and you shouldn't do that. I guess maybe some _libraries_ check the pointer and exit if it's not theirs, but they don't have to. Just don't do it.