# Why I can not delete the following pointer?

Tags: c++

```
int main()
{
    int x = 3;
    int* y = new int(4);
    y = &x;
    cout << y;
    delete y;
}
```

it shows the following error:

> Error in './a.out':free(): invalid pointer:0x00007ffde8e1c0364
>
> 0x7ffde8e1c0364 Aborted

Comment: What do you expect `y=&x; delete y;` to do?

Comment: After doing `y=&x;` the pointer no longer points to some memory that was allocated with `new` but to a address from the local stack.

Comment: @NathanOliver it should deallocate memory allocated to y dynamically

Comment: @AmitKumar Why?  You assigned `y` the address of `x`.  It doesn't have the avalue of the memory it had before when you do that.

Comment: Dynamically allocated memory is never automatically deallocated in C++. If you want dynamic memory to be deallocated without having to manually intervene you can use standard library features that implement that behavior like `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ so can we say that delete can deallocate only those variable whose adress does not lie in stack .Thanks πάντα ῥεῖ

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux but what for manually deallocation of memory

Comment: @AmitKumar I do not understand your last reply.

Comment: @AmitKumar "_so can we say that delete can deallocate only those variable whose adress does not lie in stack_" Not exactly. You can only `delete` what you `new`.

Comment: @AmitKumar You don't deallocate variables, only memory.

Answer (score 9):

`y` cannot be deleted because it points to a an object with automatic storage after the line

```
y = &x;
```

Only an address returned by `new` may be deleted. If the operand of `delete` has some other value (such as address of an automatic object, as in the example) the behaviour of the program will be undefined.

The quoted assignment overwrites the previous value, which was the only copy of the address of the dynamic allocation. This loss of the address is called a "memory leak", since the dynamic allocation can no longer be released.

Answer (score 6):

`delete` destroys objects previously allocated by `new`, but `x` was not allocated by `new`. Your code is the same as:

```cpp
int x=3;
delete &x;
```

See Also:

- [new expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new)
- [delete expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/delete)

Comment: Technically speaking: C++ standard doesn't define "stack", or "heap", in the sense of variable storage. There are only "automatic storage duration", and "dynamic storage duration".

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius there is also thread_local and static storage durations.

Comment: Yes? How were they relevant to this question, or you answer (as in: "_`delete` deletes from the heap, but `x` is on the stack._")? I was just stating, that the words like "stack", and "heap"  mentioned in your answer, doesn't appear in C++ standard in regards to variable storage.

Comment: You said, "there are only", but apparently I misunderstood you.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius updated answer per your feedback

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to dereference `y` and assign to `x`.

```
int main()
{
    int x = 3;
    int* y = new int(4);
    *y = x;
    cout << y;
    delete y;
}
```

I don't get any core dumps with that.

Comment: This is not wrong, but I don't believe it answers the question (**Why** delete cannot be called on the pointer.)

Comment: In addition to the above, minor nitpick: "_I don't get any core dumps with that._" If you don't get core dump with a specific piece of code, in several executions, of it, it doesn't, automatically, prove, that the code is free of undefined behavior.

Comment: @BenJones  Is it because 'y'  is assigned a value equal to the address of  'x' ?

Comment: assigning the address `&x` to the pointer `y` is perfectly valid.  The issue is that [you cannot `delete` an object allocated on the stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441831/calling-delete-on-variable-allocated-on-the-stack).

Answer (score 0):

When you do `int x = 3;`, x is stored on stack. After `y = &x`, pointer y points to an element in stack. When you try to delete stack memory, you get a coredump as `delete` works only on memory allocated on heap.

Answer (score 0):

Because `delete auto-storage-class` is not a supported use of `operator delete`.

In the statement, `int* y = new int(4);`, you use `operator new` to perform an allocation.

However, in the statement, `y = &x;`, you change the pointer to `auto int x = 3;`.

An `auto` storage class variable is allocated by the C/C++ runtime and never by the user. This is the reason it is an error to try and `delete &x;`.