# C++ Deleting pointer with function

Tags: c++, pointers

I have one question. Is it possible to delete a pointer with function? This is my example:

```cpp
void deletePointer(auto* pointer)
{
    delete pointer;
    pointer = nullptr;
}

int main()
{
    int value = 5;
    int* value_ptr = &value;

    //Some code

    deletePointer(value_ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

And it doesn't work. I also tried adding "inline" keyword to function and with lambda.

```cpp
auto deletePointer = [&](auto* pointer) -> void
{
    delete pointer;
    pointer = nullptr;
}
```

I think it only deletes pointer inside of function, lambda. Is it possible to make function that will delete pointer, which is passing to function?

Comment: You can only `delete` what you `new`ed, your first snippet is invalid.

Comment: Also, you don't want to pass the pointer 'by value' if you want to edit where it is pointing. If you declare deletepointer as "void deletePointer(auto * & pointer), you can let it point to nullptr outside the scope of the function, in case you're wondering why value_ptr == nullptr is false .

Comment: Oh, you're right. This solves my problem. Thanks :)

Comment: Also I have another question. Am I supposed to delete pointers which are pointing a variable (without `new`)?

Comment: @MiłoszBrzechczyn no you must not delete pointers allocated on the stack, as Mat indicated, see for instance the answer in  [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441831/calling-delete-on-variable-allocated-on-the-stack). Even more, even if used correctly, raw pointers are to be avoided, as they are in most cases considered code-smells, and to be replaced my more modern memory management

Comment: @MiłoszBrzechczyn for the future: If you come up with an answer to your own  question, it is easier for others who encounter a similar problem if you post your answer separate from the question in the answer area, and leave the question itself unchanged. After a certain time passed, you're then able to accept you're own answer, s.th. it is shown with a green answer check mark.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will do it.

Comment: I got message: "You can accept your own answer in 2 days". So I must wait.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution.

I got to know that `delete` can be used only when object is creating using `new`. So I  changed code a bit.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

void deletePointer(auto*& pointer)
{
    delete pointer;
    pointer = nullptr;
}

int main()
{
    int* ptr = new int(5);

    deletePointer(ptr);

    if (ptr == nullptr) std::cout << "Succeed";
    else std::cout << "Failed";

    return 0;
}
```

And given output from code is: `Succeed`.
So now everything works.
Thanks for help :)