# C++ disable const for the type

Tags: c++, c++20

Please note a variation of the classic singly-linked-list structure below:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

struct Node;

struct SList {
    Node* root = nullptr;
};

struct Node {
    int* data = nullptr;
    SList* parent = nullptr;
    Node* next = nullptr;

    Node(Node const&) = delete;
    Node& operator=(Node const&) = delete;

    constexpr Node(int data, SList& list)
        : data(new int(data)), parent(&list), next(list.root) {
        list.root = this;
    }

    constexpr ~Node() {
        Node** p = &parent->root;
        while (*p != this) {
            p = &((*p)->next);
        }
        (*p) = this->next;
        delete data;
    }
};

constexpr int test() {
    SList list;

    Node n1(10, list);
    Node n2(20, list);
    Node n3(30, list);
    { Node n3_5(35, list); }
    auto pn4 = new Node(40, list);
    Node n5 = Node(50, list);
    delete pn4;

    int sum = 0;
    for (auto p = list.root; p; p = p->next) {
        sum += *p->data;
    }
    return sum;
}

int main() {
    auto constexpr retval = test();
    return retval;
}
```

There is a very subtle bug in there. If any of the references are const (like `Node const n2(20, list);`), we're storing a non-const pointer to a const object in the constructor of `Node`. This pointer is then used in the destructor of other other `Node` objects and cause undefined behavior. Making `Node* next` mutable is not an option because you can't use mutable fields in a constexpr function.

This structure is inherently not const-friendly. I either want to fix this code somehow, so it doesn't silently cause UB for all const instances, or disable creating const objects of type `Node` entirely (as a compile-time error). Since objects are not const in their constructor, I am not sure how one would do either of those.

Comment: For disabling the creation of const Nodes you can set the constructor to private: let the SList friend the Node and place the construction of nodes in SList.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe you show me how to do that (perhaps in an answer)?

Comment: I think you can just make `next` as `mutable`, if you really need to implement linked-list in this dangerous way in my opinion.

Comment: @VainMan as I noted in the question, making `next` mutable makes it not usable in constexpr functions.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili oh sorry, I don't know how could I miss that...

Comment: Is "pimpl idiom" on `Node` an acceptable option ?

Comment: @VainMan unfortunately no. The point of this is to have light-weight nodes on the stack that clean up after themselves.

Comment: Is this not applicable? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441831/calling-delete-on-variable-allocated-on-the-stack

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe how is that relevant at all?